# TypeScript - check a variable of type unknown has certain property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relay

I'm using typescript in `relay` and the `props` passed down is of type `unknown`. I have tried several ways to convince the compiler that it can have some property but it keeps showing me an error:

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={environment}
  query={testQuery}
  variables={{}}
  render={({ error, props }) => {
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error!</div>;
    }
    if (!props) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (!!props && _.isObject(props) && props.hasOwnProperty("Messages"))
      return <MessageList messages={props.Messages} />;
  }}
/>;
```

The above code doesn't work, typescript still warns me that

> Property 'Messages' does not exist on type 'object'.

How to make this simple example work yet not make my code look hideous? Many thanks!

Comment: `<MessageList messages={ (props as { Messages : string }).Messages } />`

Comment: @januwa That is quick and nice, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. You should be able to solve this without type assertion (`as`). It should know the correct type as per the docs, but I'm also getting props as type `unknown` 
https://relay.dev/docs/en/type-emission

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate the specific GraphTaggedNode from your query. This will be your query's name from your `testQuery` variable. In my example below I have called it TestQuery. But it should be prefixed with the `FileName_Query` in pascal case.

Your `props` should now be annotated with `TestQueryResponse`.

```
<QueryRenderer<TestQuery>
  ...
 />
```